# Express request object not correctly reporting https

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to auto-redirect users of my site to https, but in order to do so I need to know if they're *already visiting* via https, otherwise I'll get into an infinite redirect loop.

From searching, I've tried looking at these values

```
console.log('!!!!!!!!!ROUTING TO REDUX!!!!!!!!', request.secure, request.protocol, request.get('X-Forwarded-Protocol'));
```

But I'm seeing this get logged

> 2017-06-23T07:20:10.996750+00:00 app[web.1]: !!!!!!!!!ROUTING TO REDUX!!!!!!!! false http undefined
>
> 2017-06-23T07:20:11.028280+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=my-library-io.herokuapp.com request_id=3fc84fae-02bd-443a-8265-c45def605ba1 fwd="64.134.226.42" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=33ms status=200 bytes=2309 protocol=https

even when viewing https.

The site is here `https://mylibrary.io/`  The original Heroku url is here `https://my-library-io.herokuapp.com/`

Both URLs load, and show as secure in my browser, but both also appear to log as https, via the second entry above; but with either I can't look at anything in the request object to surmise that I'm viewing via https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`request.get('X-Forwarded-Proto')`](https://github.com/nodenica/node-heroku-ssl-redirect/blob/master/index.js#L10), as opposed to `X-Forwarded-Protocol`. As you can see, it is used by the npm package [`heroku-ssl-redirect`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/heroku-ssl-redirect). This *de-facto* standard HTTP header is also [documented on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Common_non-standard_request_fields).